Zorn's Lemma in Topos Theory
I am reading the book "Sheaves in Geometry and Logic". When constructing the topos of sets, there is a proposition (proposition 8 of the "Topos of sets" subchapter) that uses Zorn's Lemma to show that certain toposes satisfy the Axiom of choice.
It's possible this is explained in the book somewhere and I just missed it, but I am slightly confused on how this is not circular, because as far as I am aware, Zorn's lemma relies on (and is equivalent to) the axiom of choice, and Elementary Toposes are not supposed to rely on ZFC set theory.
Is Zorn's lemma just taken as a fundamental axiom of thin categories (that is, posets that need not be sets), or am I missing something? Preemptive thank you to anyone who can help clarify this for me.

I don't have that book, but...  Could it just be that it's showing that if the "base universe" where topoi live satisfies axiom of choice and therefore Zorn's lemma, then certain topoi constructed in that base universe also satisfy an internal or external version of the axiom of choice?  (Which is certainly not automatic for general topoi even in such a base universe.)

@DanielSchepler Could be. The full proposition is "Let $\mathcal{E}$ be a topos which is generated by subobjects of 1, and moreover has the property that for each object $E$, $Sub(E)$ is a
complete Boolean algebra. Then $\mathcal{E}$ satisfies the axiom of choice". The proof derives a contradiction from the Zorn's lemma applied to $Sub(E)$.

Zorn’s Lemma is assumed to be true in the actual category of sets - that is, the metatheory includes Zorn’s Lemma. We then use this fact to show that the Axiom of Choice holds in other categories - specifically, Boolean localic toposes. There is nothing circular about this.
It’s worth noting there is no way to prove this theorem without relying on Zorn’s Lemma (or some other equivalent of the Axiom of Choice) in the category of sets, since the category of sets is itself a Boolean localic topos. We are actually required to rely on this axiom when reasoning about “real sets”, though we cannot rely on it when we are reasoning about “set theory” in the internal logic of an arbitrary topos.
